# Can't create custom setters for android data binding - "Could not find accessor" error

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to create custom setter as described here:
https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#custom_setters

My view is:

```
<data>
        <variable name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.feed.DummyViewModel" />
</data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.imageUrl}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Binding is:

```
package com.example.feed;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DummyViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url) {
// nothing yet
    }
}
```

Wen building I get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
 ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.example.feed.DummyViewModel.imageUrl file:/Users/tse/t/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml loc:20:28 - 20:45 ****\ data binding error ****
```

What is wrong with my `loadImage` function? How to make correct binding adapter?

Answer (score 5):

Could not find accessor com.example.feed.DummyViewModel.imageUrl

> DummyViewModel don't have get method: getImageUrl()

also you can define public:

```
public String imageUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you don't actually store the url anywhere. Try something like this:

```
public class DummyViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    public String imageUrl;

    @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url) {
        // nothing yet
    }
}
```

Then wherever it is that you create an instance of the DummyViewModel set the imageUrl field to the Url of the image. Something like this:

```
DummyViewModel viewModel = new DummyViewModel();
viewModel.imageUrl = "your_image_url_here";
MyViewBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_view, container, false);
dataBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

In rare cases as mine, Android studio generates getter and setter for your fields with unexpected signature than databinding would expect that signature.Let me show you by example
I have a field `private long pT;` when i use android tool "Generate Getter and Setter"
the generated methods looks like

```
public long getpT() {
    return pT;
}
public void setpT(long pT) {
    this.pT = pT;
}
```

As you can see the usual method signature start with get and set followed by the field name after capitalization of first character of the field name in mine it did not so i manually correct it to be`getPT` and `setPT` then the problem solved .
So care must be taken when writting accessor for your variables.